# Minimum Network Requirements for connecting to servers in other countries

Tags: networking

I'd like to know the minimum network requirements when working with servers in other countries. example,
 I work in Australia and my company needs to download files from another companies server located in Spain.

I would appreciate a link to a source where I can read more about this.

Thank you

Comment: An internet connection on both ends to provide connectivity between the two systems and a mutually agreed upon transfer protocol/method. Done.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing, what you probably need is to figure out what kind of apps each office will use and find out the requirements for each app, add things up and you'll end up with the right connection speed for each office.

The connection type that you'll get depends on the SLA level you wanted to achieve, prices and availability in your country.